# how to make a box clickable

Tags: html, css

[The menu image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/il0HA.png)

Hello, I have a menu list that looks like like the image above. When I hover over it, the color changes but it is not clickable until I hover on the text itself. How can I make the box clickable when I hover over it?

Thank you so much for any help.

```css
    a
    {
     text-decoration: none;
     color: inherit;
    
    }
    
    
    nav ul
    {
     background-color: #f49d33;
     overflow: hidden;
     color: white;
     padding: 0;
     text-align: center;
     -webkit-transition: max-height 0.4s;
     -ms-transition: max-height 0.4s;
     -moz-transition: max-height 0.4s;
     -o-transition: max-height 0.4s;
     transition: max-height 0.4s;
    
    }
    
    nav ul li 
    {
     display: inline-block;
     padding: 20px;
    
    }
    
    nav ul li:hover 
    {
     background-color: #e8d75c;
    
    
    }
```

```html
    <nav>
    
        <ul>
         <li><a href="addCustomer.php"> Add Customer </a></li>
         <li><a href="changePassword.php"> Change Password </a></li>
         <li><a href="View_and_delete_orders.php"> View & Delete Orders  </a></li>
         <li><a href="#"> View & Delete Customers  </a></li>
         <li><a href="#"> Messages </a></li>
         <li><a href="index.php"> Log out </a></li>
        </ul>
       
    </nav>
```

Comment: Use display: block; for the links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the padding to your `a` and make it `inline-block`. I would also use the `:hover` pseudo class on the `a`, not the `li`

```css
    a
    {
     text-decoration: none;
     color: inherit;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 20px;        
    }
    
    
    nav ul
    {
     background-color: #f49d33;
     overflow: hidden;
     color: white;
     padding: 0;
     text-align: center;
     -webkit-transition: max-height 0.4s;
     -ms-transition: max-height 0.4s;
     -moz-transition: max-height 0.4s;
     -o-transition: max-height 0.4s;
     transition: max-height 0.4s;
    
    }
    
    nav ul li 
    {
     display: inline-block;
    }
    
    nav ul li a:hover 
    {
     background-color: #e8d75c;
    
    
    }
```

```html
    <nav>
    
        <ul>
         <li><a href="addCustomer.php"> Add Customer </a></li>
         <li><a href="changePassword.php"> Change Password </a></li>
         <li><a href="View_and_delete_orders.php"> View & Delete Orders  </a></li>
         <li><a href="#"> View & Delete Customers  </a></li>
         <li><a href="#"> Messages </a></li>
         <li><a href="index.php"> Log out </a></li>
        </ul>
       
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the li label padding value on the a label

Comment: a
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
    display: block;
 padding: 20px;
}

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is simple:

`padding: 20px` on `<a>` made a gap between the edge of `<a>` and `<li>`. Move `padding: 20px` from `<li>` to `<a>` can solve this problem.